# Como mover o Form com o BorderStyle em bsNone

Tags: delphi, delphi-10

Como eu faço para mover o form apos setar a propriedade `BorderStyle = bsNone`?
Pois em as bordas não consigo arrastar o formulário com o mouse.

Comment: Você já tem algum código pronto para que possa ser analisado?

Comment: Não tenho. Eu só coloquei a propriedade BorderStyle = bsNone no Object Inspector.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Achei isso em um [forum](https://www.devmedia.com.br/forum/arrastar-forms-com-o-borderstyle-em-bsnone/409660), tenta ai para ver se funciona.

```
procedure TFormPrincipal.ImageFundoMouseDown(Sender: TObject;
  Button: TMouseButton; Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
const
   sc_DragMove = $f012;
begin
  ReleaseCapture;
  Perform(wm_SysCommand, sc_DragMove, 0);
end;
```

Comment: blz cara. vou testar aqui para ver se funfa.